# Random display of a character in Godot 4

Tags: godot, random, godot-4

I made a character in Godot 4 that enters from one side of the image and exits from the other side, which shows its different modes randomly each time.
I have written these codes for it:

```
extends RigidBody2D

@export var min_speed = 150.0
@export var max_speed = 250.0


func _ready():
    $AnimatedSprite2D.playing = true
    var mob_types = $AnimatedSprite2D.frames.get_animation_names()
    $AnimatedSprite2D.animation = mob_types[randi() % mob_types.size()]


func _on_visible_on_screen_notifier_2d_screen_exited():
    queue_free()
```

but when I press the F5 key, it displays this error:

> Invalid set index 'playing'(on base: 'AnimatedSprite2D')with value of type 'bool'.

What is the problem?
How should I write the codes?

Answer (score 3):

The error is telling you that [`AnimatedSprite2D`](https://docs.godotengine.org/en/stable/classes/class_animatedsprite2d.html) does not have a `playing` property (to which you are trying assign a `bool`).

The `AnimatedSprite2D` can hold multiple animations, and you are supposed to tell it which one you want to play by calling the `play` method:

```
$AnimatedSprite2D.play(&"NameOfMyAnimation")
```

Or by setting the `animation` property (which are already doing).

Thus, I believe that removing the offending line is sufficient to make your code work.